# Termus/Python - How to mark unread SMS messages as read?

Tags: sms, termux, python

I made a simple SMS reader script with Python and Termux/Termux API (I use termux-tts-speak to read the messagees and execute the script from Termux). The script reads messages (with termux-sms-list) marked as unread. So I want to mark the messages as read after they are read by the script. How can I do this?